# How to limit first level comments in Praw Reddit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Is it possible to limit first level comments which `replace_more` function returns?

```
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=1)
```

Or remove all `MoreComments` objects from the first level? I mean I'd like to limit comments tree `height` and get maximum `width` (get all comments which go from limited amount of the first level comments).

Comment: can you clarify what "first level" comments means? Do you want to get only the comments that are direct replies to the post (so, skipping all comments which are replies to other comments)?

Comment: "first level" in Reddit api has its own parameter: `depth=0`. It is the first level of each branch of comments tree.

Comment: The most left comments on the reddit page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `replace_more`, just replace each `MoreComments` object as you get to it. This will prevent you from replacing any `MoreComments` objects that are not at the top level.

Below is a function that will iterate through top-level comments, replacing each `MoreComments` as it is encountered. This is inspired by [example code from the PRAW documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html#extracting-comments-with-praw):

```
from praw.models import MoreComments

def iter_top_level(comments):
    for top_level_comment in comments:
        if isinstance(top_level_comment, MoreComments):
            yield from iter_top_level(top_level_comment.comments())
        else:
            yield top_level_comment
```

The way this generator works is that it yields top-level comments from the submission, but when it encounters a `MoreComments` object, it loads those comments and recursively calls itself. The recursive call is necessary because in large threads, each `MoreComments` object contains another top-level `MoreComments` object at the end.

Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
submission = reddit.submission('fgi5bd')
for comment in iter_top_level(submission.comments): 
    print(comment.author)
```